# Convert VARCHAR a column in SQL to datetime format?

Tags: sql, date, db2, cloud, ibm-cloud

time(varchar)

```
2020-07-19T02:28:22.729Z
2020-07-19T02:48:33.979Z
2020-07-19T02:48:48.250Z
2020-07-19T02:53:24.307Z
2020-07-19T02:53:48.278Z
```

I wanted to change this columntime(varchar) to date timeformat in ibm cloud?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: All databases have a bunch of string, convert/cast and datetime functions which will allow you to accomplish what you are looking for, Please check the documentation for your database product.

Answer (score 0):

Both MySQL and SQL Server (the original tags) understand this format, so you can use:

```
cast('2020-07-19T02:28:22.729Z' as datetime)
```

in both databases, or using the column name:

```
cast(time as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want to turn your string to a `timestamp` rather than a `date`, since it contains milliseconds. In DB2, you can use `to_timestamp()` for this. You would need to first remove the middle `'T'` and then trailing `'Z'`.

This should do it:

```
to_timestamp(
    replace(replace('2020-07-19T02:28:22.729Z', 'T', ' '), 'Z', ' '),
    'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3'
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=8102beb563509fc358d5212f29d72d35)**:

```
select to_timestamp(
    replace(replace('2020-07-19T02:28:22.729Z', 'T', ' '), 'Z', ' '),
    'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3'
) ts from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

```
|                               TS |
| -------------------------------: |
| 2020-07-19 02:28:22.729000000000 |
```

Comment: how do i retrieve the time from mu another column , i am using this query "select to_timestamp(
    replace(replace('Select "time" from QUAKE', 'T', ' '), 'Z', ' '),
    'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3'
) ts from sysibm.sysdummy1" i am getting an error like " Error message
"Select "time" from QUAKE" cannot be interpreted using format string "yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.ff3" for the TIMESTAMP_FORMAT function.. SQLCODE=-20448, SQLSTATE=22007, DRIVER=4.26.14
Learn more about this error"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/*
WITH QUAKE (time) AS
(
VALUES
  '2020-07-19T02:28:22.729Z'
, '2020-07-19T02:48:33.979Z'
, '2020-07-19T02:48:48.250Z'
, '2020-07-19T02:53:24.307Z'
, '2020-07-19T02:53:48.278Z'
)
*/
SELECT TIMESTAMP(TRANSLATE(time, ' ', 'TZ'))
FROM QUAKE;
```